# Duplicate Data is Inserted

Tags: php

when i insert data my select query is not working and data is directly insert. My search query is not working but data is directly inserted.please help me.how my serach query is start please check the code.

````
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])=="")
    {   
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
    else{
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$classname=$_POST['classname'];
$classnamenumeric=$_POST['classnamenumeric']; 
$section=$_POST['section'];
$q="SELECT * FROM tblclasses Where (ClassName='$classname' AND Section='$section');";
      $res=mysqli_query($dbh,$q);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if($classname==$row['ClassName'] &&  $section==$row['Section'])
        {
         echo '<script>alert("already exists")</script>';
        }

}else{
$sql="INSERT INTO  tblclasses(ClassName,ClassNameNumeric,Section) VALUES(:classname,:classnamenumeric,:section)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':classname',$classname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':classnamenumeric',$classnamenumeric,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':section',$section,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
if($lastInsertId)
{
$msg="Class Created successfully";
}
else 
{
$error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
}
}
}
?>```
````

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks and should use [paramaterized prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data in your queries like that. You're actually doing it correctly in your `INSERT`-statement.

Comment: Post['submit'] is not defined.

Comment: You are mixing PDO prepared statements and mysqli_ select/fetch statements. What actually is `$dbh`? Ideally it should be a PDO object, and you use _only_ PDO `prepare()/bindParam()/execute()`. If it is a mysqli object, you will need to use mysqli's prepared statements.

Comment: I don't know any PHP, but don't you need to commit your INSERT ?

Comment: Always when developing and testing code, enable all error reporting.You've explicitly disabled it, so PHP won't give you any feedback. At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1)`

Comment: @reportgunner no, not usually. Autocommit is enabled by default in most apis.